# In $\Delta ABC$ if $a,b,c$ are in Harmonic Progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

In $\Delta ABC$ if $a,b,c$ are in Harmonic Progression Then Prove that

$$\sin ^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right),\sin ^2\left(\frac{B}{2}\right),\sin ^2\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$ are in Harmonic Progression

My Try:

we have

$$\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{b}$$  Then

$$\frac{a-b}{a}=\frac{b-c}{c}$$ and by Sine Rule

$$ \frac{\sin A-\sin B}{\sin A}=\frac {\sin B-\sin C}{\sin C}$$ $\implies$

$$\frac{2\sin \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)}{2\sin \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)}=\frac{2\sin \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)}{2\sin \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)}$$  $\implies$

$$\sin ^2\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\left(2\cos \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\right)=\sin ^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\left(2\cos \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)\right)$$ $\implies$

$$\sin ^2\left(\frac{C}{2}\right) \left(\sin B+\sin A\right)=\sin ^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right) \left(\sin B+\sin C\right)$$

Any way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use cosine rule of triangle

and $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$ for $A,B,C$ to express $\sin^2$  half angles in terms of $a,b,c$

Comment: i tried that way but its very tedious

Answer (score 0):

We need $\csc^2$ half angles in arithmetic progression

$\iff\cot^2$ in arithmetic progression

Use $\cot\dfrac A2=\dfrac{s(s-a)}\triangle$

Comment: Ya got it but a typo in your post $\cot  \frac{A}{2}=\frac{s(s-a)}{\Delta}$

Comment: @Ekaveera, see https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_triangles_by_half-angle_formulae

Comment: Yes i have seen observe clearly $$\tan \frac{A}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{(s-b)(s-c)}}{\sqrt{s(s-a)}}=\frac{\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}{s(s-a)}=\frac{\Delta}{s(s-a)}$$

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma, Then we have $\cot$s are in Arithmetic Progression, right? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877784/trigonometric-arithmetic-progression. Then $\cot^2$ can not be unless all of them are same!

Answer (score 0):

Given 
\begin{align} 
b &= 2\,\frac{ac}{a+c}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\end{align}
prove that
\begin{align} 
\sin^2\tfrac\beta2&=
2\,\frac{\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2 \sin^2\tfrac\gamma2}{\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2+\sin^2\tfrac\gamma2}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

Using the half-angle formulas
\begin{align}
\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2
&=\frac{(s-b)(s-c)}{bc}=\tfrac14\,\frac{(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}{bc}
,\\
\sin^2\tfrac\gamma2
&=\frac{(s-a)(s-b)}{ab}=\tfrac14\,\frac{(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)}{ab}
,\\
\sin^2\tfrac\beta2
&=\frac{(s-a)(s-c)}{ac}=\tfrac14\,\frac{(-a+b+c)(a+b-c)}{ac}
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

with $b$ from \eqref{1},
it follows that indeed \eqref{3}=\eqref{2}.

Tested in `Maxima`:

```
(%i1) display2d:false$
(%i2) declare([a,b,c,sa,sb,sc],real)$
(%i3) halfSinSqred(a,b,c):=1/4*(a-b+c)*(a+b-c)/b/c$
(%i4) b:2*a*c/(a+c)$
(%i5) sa:factor(halfSinSqred(a,b,c));
(%o5) -((c^2+a^2)*(c^2-2*a*c-a^2))/(8*a*c^2*(c+a))
(%i6) sc:factor(halfSinSqred(c,a,b));
(%o6) ((c^2+a^2)*(c^2+2*a*c-a^2))/(8*a^2*c*(c+a))
(%i7) sb:factor(halfSinSqred(b,c,a));
(%o7) -((c^2-2*a*c-a^2)*(c^2+2*a*c-a^2))/(4*a*c*(c+a)^2)
(%i8) sbharm:factor(2*sa*sc/(sa+sc));
(%o8) -((c^2-2*a*c-a^2)*(c^2+2*a*c-a^2))/(4*a*c*(c+a)^2)
(%i9) factor(sb-sbharm);
(%o9) 0
(%i10) quit();
```